# XSLT 2.0 producing corrupt data

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a 150Mb XML file and I am trying to fetch dates with Saxon:

```
<DueDate><xsl:value-of select="billduedate"/></DueDate>
```

In the original XML file `<billduedate>` is same for all child nodes - `<billduedate>2015-12-25</billduedate>` and there are 34711 instances of them. Somehow in the result xml I get 42 `<DueDate>` tags that hold non date values. For example:

```
<DueDate>t&gt;15-12-25</DueDate>
<DueDate>t015-12-25</DueDate>
<DueDate>ta15-12-25</DueDate>
<DueDate>tamou12-25</DueDate>
<DueDate>total12-25</DueDate>
<DueDate>unt5-12-25</DueDate>
<DueDate>voi5-12-25</DueDate>
```

For other 34669  tags the date is correctly `<DueDate>2015-12-25</DueDate>`. 
And I repeat - in the original file there are no issues with dates. Am I facing some kind of Java memory issue? How to overcome it?

Comment: you could try to run it with another processor to see if it is saxon specific

Comment: Which Saxon version exactly is that? How do you run Saxon, from the command line, within a Java program?

Comment: version is HE 9.6.0.7
I'm running it from Linux command line:
net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:template2_1.xsl -o:output.xml
At the moment of running I have at least 4gigs of free memory.

Comment: Try to report the issue with Saxonica at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon, I am sure if you can give them the XSLT and the XML input to reproduce the issue they will work on fixing it.

Comment: I accidentally discovered that once I change XML output from ver 1.1 to 1.0 then the problem disappears. Good people from Saxonica will take closer look at it and then I hope to give final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Michael Kay(Saxonica):

I have reproduced the problem (with the built-in JDK parser com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser), and I have established that the data is corrupt at the point where it is passed from the XML parser to Saxon. I was using JDK 1.6.0.27 here.

The problem is not present when I switch to JDK 1.8.0_25.

I have also established that the problem goes away when you use the Xerces parser from Apache (org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser)

Conclusion: bug in JDK XML parser.